# Why is Mongo giving me the E11000 error even though I don't have any field set to unique?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm getting this error when saving the second document to MongoDB atlas:

`error:MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.orders index: orderId_1 dup key: { orderId: null }`

However, in the document schema, I do not have any field set to unique:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
    paymentId: {
        type: Number
    },
    paymentStatus: {
        type: String
    },
    paymentToken: {
        type: String
    },
    orderDetails: {
        type: Object
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

What does the error mean?
I am saving it like this:

```
const newOrder = new Order({
        paymentId, 
        paymentStatus, 
        orderDetails,
        paymentToken
    });
    
    newOrder.save()
        .then(() => console.log("order saved!"))
        .catch(err => console.log("error:" + err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is referencing an OrderId_1 that I don't see in your model.  I would check compass or atlas to make sure you don't have a "Unique" Index set.

Comment: thank you! I had an OrderId_1 index set to unique.